# My microphone was falling off the table and I do not know if it is working properly

Tags: recording

My microphone was falling off the table and I do not know if it is working properly ? I have a SAMSON Meteorite desktop USB microphone. There are no external causes on it. It just fell down many times with me, but it works fine. Is it possible that something has been damaged and it will become worse to record, or if it records sound, then everything is OK / everything works as it should?

now , if the microphone didn 't record sounds , then would there be a problem ? and if it records, then nothing is damaged?

Why am I asking just not sure if everything is ok. Maybe my records have gotten worse - that's what I'm worried about.

Comment: Without actually hearing a recording using this mic, there's no way to usefully answer the question. Could be the mic, could be the plug, could be the wire, how could we know?

Comment: If you can’t *hear* a difference then there’s nothing to worry about, except why you haven’t saved up for a mic stand yet.

Comment: Agreeing with Todd - a mic stand - especially a table top stand, is quite cheap in comparison to the mic, and will save you a lot of heartache for the future - and maybe the extra expense of replacing the mic when it finally does get fed up with falling onto the floor, which condenser mics do find hard to cope with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a condenser microphone. They are in general less robust than dynamic microphones. Though I wouldn't advise dropping a dynamic microphone either.

There is no way for us to tell you if something actually has been damaged. In the end, you have to trust your ears anyway.